# scrollable not working when adaptive mode is true

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-js-modal

I'm using this [plugin](http://vue-js-modal.yev.io/) in my project for modal functionality, the problem is when I use `:adaptive="true"` I can not scroll the modal when the modal height is bigger than the screen, how can I solve this.?

I also throw a [issue](https://github.com/euvl/vue-js-modal/issues/674) on their github repo, but I'm not getting any response from the author, please anyone here, who solves this problem..? If you share, then it would help me a lot and other people also.

#### Version:

`"vue-js-modal": "^2.0.0-rc.6"`

#### This my setup

```html
<modal name="quick-view"
       width="90%"
       height="auto"
       :maxWidth="1000"
       :maxHeight="600"
       :adaptive="true"
       :scrollable="true">

     long content goes here
     .......................................................................
     ........................................................................
     ........................................................................
</modal>
```

is my setup is correct or I missed something..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue here, but I was able to fix it with the css code below... found on this post https://github.com/euvl/vue-js-modal/issues/674#issuecomment-844301259

```
.vm--modal {
  height: auto !important;
}
```